# Counting and displaying records with paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to count records returned from a search query.

The problem is that I am using the Model Count with paging.  It will not display the Model Count for records not on the first page of the returned search query.

The code I am using:

```
 @String.Format("Total of {0} results", Model.Count()) @ViewBag.CurrentFilter
```

Model count ())    used for the counting of files

@ViewBag.CurrentFilter is used for the name of the search query

Below is the code for the controler

```
            int pageSize = 4;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            var carsviewd = cars.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            if (carsviewd.Any())
            {
                return View(carsviewd);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("NoResult");
        }


    }
```

Comment: show us your controller code. controller is the place where your count should be done as view will get only part of the results when you are using paging

Comment: Question updated with Controller code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In controller before return view,you can use:

```
ViewBag.Count =  cars.Count();
```

then in the View you can use the following：

```
@String.Format("Total of {0} results", ViewBag.Count)
```

Comment: the first answer you gave was correct just a problem with the variable